# So bad at math sometimes I feel depressed about it.

Tags: education, advice

I taught myself how to count before I even learned how to talk or read. Playing with numbers was all I did when I was young. I didn't have anyone to foster that type of passion that I believe I still have.

I went to a school where teachers didn't care about math, mostly because none of them knew how to do it. It wasn't until I had started secondary school, in 8th grade, that I finally knew how a fraction works or what it does. My bad luck doesn't stop there; after going to high school, my 6th, 7th, and 8th grade math teachers were so bad at math that they aren't even allowed to teach mathematics anymore today. They genuinely did not do anything. My knowledge was a reflection of this.

When I was in 9th grade I started learning how to do Algebra because we got a new teacher. I actually learned something. From 9th to 11th grade I taught myself how to do math up to a Calculus 1 level. It was very hard in such a quick period of time. I saw some improvements. The textbooks we used are the worst in the country because the school I go to is poor. I can't afford a tutor because I don't have hundreds of dollars to spare every week for it.

I've just finished 11th grade. I dropped math completely. The highest mark for the yearly was 100%, to someone who goes tutoring. The highest mark for non-tutor students was 53%. That person spent his whole two weeks doing nothing but math, but only got 53%. Nearby schools meanwhile get averages of min. 90%, easily.

But I still want to do math, and I don't know how to continue this. What should I do? I think about it a lot and I feel so depressed and embarrassed knowing how bad at math I am. I don't think it's hard to self-teach with my level of understanding, but I need the right book that has everything. I think I am at a level were I can take matters into my own hands.

I know this site hates these types of questions, but sorry, I don't know where else to come. What should I do in my situation? Khan Academy is bad for my case. It teaches a lot of concepts, but all at a basic level. I need something that goes from the ground - up. I want to master Calculus 3 by the end of the year.

Comment: I realised after my graduation that i want to do math . I started forno reason and looked for youtube videos and i am doing what i love for past2 years .just keep on ..

Comment: If you really master calculus 3 as i learned it on my own from youtube video by prof adrian banner of princeton university . See them and youwill not haveany problem in calc 3 .believe

Comment: A side note you are already up on some of the kids I tutor, by having a passion for mathematics. At this level it is like going to the gym..you work hard you will get into shape (forget comparing yourself to other people worry about yourself and you will be fine! Great even!) .. But carrying on the gym analogy, you will not be "buff" or "fit" after one session, or worse without the prior morivation. So keep up your passion and push on through! Good luck

Comment: try harder ....

Comment: For the emotional part of your situation: Nothing’s lost, I think. I wouldn’t worry too much. Don’t be embarassed, don’t feel ashamed, don’t feel bad: Everything’s fine. For the actual advice on studying calculus: I don’t know.

Comment: Comparison is worst thing that can happen to anyone .its like hurting child .please dont do it

Comment: I am in the same situation. Try to do math for the fun of doing it. Regarding the resources, Khan Academy is horrible. MITOCW is better but not as good. Books are your best friend. Just do a simple search on this website "reference request for <topic>" and you will get great books for any level. BTW, try to learn math the "proper" bottom up way. Don't fall in the calculus trap. Start with set theory, number theory, algebra, geometry etc. and check if it interests you. Then proceed with more advanced topic related to that topic like real analysis etc.

Comment: Also comparing yourself with anyone is stupid. I failed at regional exam for IMO selection and I felt I was stupid too. But now that I think of it, it looks like a very new opportunity was opened for me to study math the way I want. There is nothing as intelligent. When attacking a problem, try to think of something unique and you never know, you may solve it.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is safe to say that most of us study math because we all love it. *Since you've already have some experience in self-learning*, I think you should go on and pursue your dreams, study what you like. You will always find someone who knows more math than you, and this is ok. This goes for all of us. Try to learn from these people, befriend them. On the other hand, you'll always know something these people don't.

I don't like to think that studying math is a competition. Study for yourself, try always hard to be the best you can. What's the point of studying what you like and being unhappy with it?

Since Khan Academy is too basic, take a look at [MIT](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/) videos. You can search for books [here](http://libgen.org/). Go for it.

Comment: “You will always find someone who knows more math than you, and this is ok. This goes for all of us.” – I think this is false by Zorn’s lemma or something.